# Wrap selection around ... in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, selection, word-wrap

Is there any way to wrap the selected text in ',",),},],> or around any symbol in Notepad++?

I have looked around all of the plugins but there is nothing similar to what Textmate or eclipse can do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notepad++: How to wrap selected text in brackets, parenthesis, quotes?](http://superuser.com/questions/104264/notepad-how-to-wrap-selected-text-in-brackets-parenthesis-quotes)

Comment: Note that the answer to this question used TextFX plugin, which may not be enabled by default.  You can enable it in the PluginManager and choose unstable plugins.

Comment: I saw that but it doesn't fully answer the question, since it only allows for {}s

Comment: I just finished making a small python script that does exactly what TextMate does (more or less), I don't know if there is a way to convert it into an actual plugin tho

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go for a real simple solution: Macros.

1. Select Text
2. Macro - Start Recording
3. Ctrl-X
4. '[' Ctrl-V ']'
5. Macro - Stop Recording
6. Macro - Save Current Recorded Macro

Within 5 minutes you should be able to get all the wraps you want and assign them to shortcuts like you need them.